# error beamertheme.sty' not found (windows 8.1)

Tags: beamer

I'm trying to set a theme for my presentation with `\usetheme(Berlin)`, but I'm getting the error `File beamertheme(.sty' not found. \usetheme(`. My `beamerthemeBerlin.sty` file it's in the directory:

`C:\Program Files (x86)\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\beamer\base\themes\theme`

So what I have to do here?

Here is my code:

```
\documentclass[xcolor=divpsnames]{beamer}
\usetheme(Berlin)
\usecolortheme[named=Maroon]{structure}
\usepackage[brazilian]{babel}
\title[ggplot2 Tutorial]{An introduction to the ggplot2 package}
\subtitle[GM-RAM]{exemplo}
\author[GM-RAM]{Gustavo}
\begin{document}
    \begin{frame}
        \titlepage
    \end{frame} 
\end{document}
```

And the code works if I comment the lines

```
\usetheme(Berlin)
\usecolortheme[named=Maroon]{structure}
```

Comment: I'm thinking the parentheses for `\usetheme` are wrong

Comment: you need {} instead of ()

Comment: ok, what a stupid error. But now I'm receveing another one: `Line 9: Package xcolor Error: Undefined color `beamer@structure@color'. \begin{document}`

Comment: ok, the error was because of typo.  I typed `\documentclass[xcolor=divpsnames]{beamer}` but I have to type: `\documentclass[xcolor=dvipsnames]{beamer}`. Sorry again.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the error was caused by two typos (see comments)